# How to use MPI_Scatterv to scatter colums of a row major matrix?

Tags: mpi

Suppose I have a Matrix and 1D Array is used to store it.

The Matrix is stored by row fast. `A(i,j)=A[i+j*num_row]`

I want scatter a part of Matrix to other process.

For example:

Process 0 own a 8x8 matrix.

I want

scatter colum 0..2 to process 0.

scatter colum 3..4 to process 1.

scatter colum 5..8 to process 2.

At these case, data send to one process is in a discontinuous space.

Futhermore, becase number of colum handled by other process may be not equal, I think the user defined data type may be can not help here.

It must can be done by mannually writing send and recv.
It must can be done by copy the data to one process to a continuous space and call `MPI_Scatterv`.

But I am confused that can `MPI_Scatterv` deal with it without data copy? If can, how to deal with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create a derived data type for a column (do not forget to resize it) and then simply `MPI_Scatter()` with `count=2`.

Comment: Thanks for hint that derived data type for a column. Would you like write it as an answer, I 'd like to accept it.

Comment: I’d rather give you a chance to do your homework and help you only if you are stuck.

Comment: I misread your question and you do need `MPI_Scatterv()`. By using a derived datatype for a column you can simply have `sendcounts={3,2,3}`

Comment: Sorry for I do not explain correctly. I mean that could you just only leave the word "using derived data type for a column" as the answer? Then I want to accept it. The detailed code is not important. I could do the things by my self. Great help for help find the clue.